# One Ethernet port installed in wall in new apartment that has fiber optics for our internet

Tags: ethernet

In the office there is only one Ethernet port in the wall but I need two for work. I work from home and need Ethernet connected to my computer and also my phone that has a POE injector connected to the phone needing a data in and data out port.

In my current apartment I have it set up through a wifi extender that has two Ethernet ports. So what do I do? Do I contact my internet provider to get a router that works with fiber optics?

Comment: You need your ISP to provide a router with a switch included (normal) that connects to the fibre

Comment: If I do this would I just have a router in the office with the second Ethernet needed connected to it?

Comment: Yes. That will work. The router will have a 4 port switch or router included.

Comment: I myself would go buy my own router.  "wifi extender" slows your speeds down significantly.

Comment: Yeah I know but I needed one because I lived in old apartment and didn’t want wires going everywhere but once I move I will no longer use it

Comment: You don't need to involve you ISP. I would give a better answer, but am struggling to see what you have and what you want. I see that you are currently powering your phone from the ether-net, this will complicate it. I don't see anything about the adaptor for the phone.  I don't see how the number of monitors is relevant. And, I see that something, though I know not what, has a data in and data out port. I see that you use Wifi in the past. Is that an option? Is the ether net fibre, or copper? Please edit question to make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

> One Ethernet port installed in wall in new apartment that has fiber
> optics for our internet

To add more devices, you do need to install a router that connects to the Fiber Optic internet.

So then ask the ISP to install a router that connects to the Fiber Optic internet.

[or provide the connection instructions if you wish to supply your own router].

A reasonably normal router includes a 4-port (or more) switch and often wireless access as well.

This will certainly allow you to hook up your computer and VOIP phone.

Assuming the router to have Wireless included (ask about this for clarification), you can also connect your smartphone devices.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I contact my internet provider to get a router that works with fiber optics?

TLDR: Yes

If your ISP is supplying you internet through fibre - You need an ONT (optical network terminal) or ONR (optical network router - which is the same thing with routing enabled, since many ONTs). In 'simplified' sense - an ONT/ONR is a 'modem' for a fibre connection and should take in the ISP supplied fibre optic cable (with some software setup on the ISP side) and give you one or more ethernet connections, depending on the set up. With an ONT, you can plug this into your 'regular' wireless router, and with a ONR, use it as a regular router (though you would need a separate device to act as a wireless access point).

While there 'are' routers (rarely consumer level) that support optical inputs - these use GPON, which is somewhat different from 'local' fibre optic lan, and most ISPs won't let you bring on your own GPON device for ease of management.

You can probably then just put a switch at the port in your room, connect the PC to that, you'd want the POE injector between the switch and the phone (though POE capable switches exist) and you'd be good